# Pinch-to-zoom UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I'm handling a pinch gesture, and I am scaling a `UILabel` like this:

```
CGFloat factor = sender.scale;
view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, factor, factor);
```

The problem is when I zoom-in (make the label larger) it wont redraw itself, i.e. it becomes blurry. How do I make it sharp again?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that transforms are applied to the rendered bitmap of the view's layer.

If you want to have the label's contents scaled adjust the contentsScale, too:

```
CGFloat scaleFactor = ...

view.layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale + scaleFactor;
view.transform           = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( scaleFactor, scaleFactor );
```